# How would I store multiple values for one set of information for a specific user in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, playframework

So I have a set of data.

Let's say the user "Jim" likes the video games with IDs 5, 15, 30, 60, and 25.

Every user in the database gets one row in a table to store information. For example, the row may include separate fields including the user's display name, age, and the date that person was active last.

Now, let's say the website Jim is on is about video games. The website has a list of games that person can say he or she likes to play, in with their own unique ID. What is the is the best way I would store that information and relate that to the user without having to store a list of the game IDs in one field?

Answer (score 1):

Three tables, one being a table of relationships between Games and Users:

```
Users (UserID, DisplayName, Age, LastActiveDate)
GamesLiked (UserID, GameID)
Games(GameID, GameName, etc)
```

GamesLiked would have 5 rows for Jim:

```
UserID  GameID
1       5
1       15
1       25
1       30
1       60
```